# How to edit an existing excel cell value into a date

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

This excel file returns the cell values (numbers from 1-30) as strings.  I convert them to integers because if it's above 16, it indicates it's a day in June.  If it's below 17 it's July (this is due to the data only searching in a one month range but that's beside the point).  I thought I could use the same variable "start" to change the cell value right there but it does not work.  Am I missing a "write" statement?  Maybe I need another variable to store what I want it to output?

Background: I'm a beginner so I don't know many ways of doing this.

```
import openpyxl
path = r"C:\Users\ms\Export.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
obj = wb_obj.active
start=""
end=""
for i in range(2, obj.max_row):
    start=obj.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    end=obj.cell(row=i, column=3).value
    try:
        if int(start)>16:
            start=("Jun-", int(start))
        elif int(start)<17:
            start=("Jul-", int(start))
        elif int(end)>16:
            end=("Jun-", int(end))
        elif int(end)<17:
            end=("Jul-", int(end))
    except:
        continue
```

I want 18 to go back into the excel file as "Jun-18",  8 to return "Jul-8", 27 to return "Jun-27" and so on.  Instead they remain at the original numbers.  Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Did you try assigning actual date or datetime objects?  And actually assigning them to the cells (as opposed to variable where you copied cell values to)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the data comes into the xlsx as just a number (i.e 18) so when it's formatted as a date it returns 1/18/1900

Comment: I'm not talking about formatting; I'm talking about making these kinds of objects in the Python code.

Comment: Have you tried actually assigning to the cells (as opposed to variables where you've copied cell values to)?

Comment: Would this be using the datetime module?  How do I add the month to the numbers in this case?  Apologies for being a beginner haha!

Comment: I was planning on editing the cell to have "Jun-18" and then the excel file could automatically format it to date

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime